# System.Security.SecurityException thrown by ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, exception

Trying to get an ASP application deployed; it worked for a while but then started coming up with errors whenever the page is accessed:

> ### Server Error in '/AppNameHere' Application.
>
> Security Exception Description: The application attempted to perform
>   an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this
>   application the required permission please contact your system
>   administrator or change the application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

An IISreset didn't change anything, but rebooting the entire system got it to work for a few hours before the problem came back. The `.config` for the application is set to full trust.

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed?  (Or, if more information is needed, where do I go looking to find it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following on [Jason Gaylord's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2007/02/13/system-web-aspnethostingpermission-when-accessing-network-or-intranet-projects-using-visual-studio-2005.aspx):

**System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission when Accessing Network or Intranet Projects using Visual Studio 2005**

I rebuilt one of my development machines recently and attempted to access a project that I had out on a network share. I continually received project messages about the project not being trusted. I remembered that I had to change something but couldn't remember what it was until I found an old note I left in Outlook.

The message I would receive in Visual Studio 2005 was: ASP.NET runtime error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

To resolve this issue, you must change your development machine .net security configuration since you are accessing items across the network. In the event that you need this ability at runtime, you must change the trust level in your config file to full. However, since this is only in development,

1. I can change my local PC's security
   by going to Start > Control Panel >
   Administrative Tools > Microsoft
   .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration.
2. After it fully loads (sometimes
   takes a bit), fully expand My
   Computer in the navigation tree and
   click Runtime Security Policy.
3. In the right hand pane, choose
       Adjust Zone Security. Leave the
       default option (Make changes to this
       computer) and hit next.
4. Choose Local Intranet and change the
       trust level to Full Trust. Then
       choose next and then finish.
5. Restart Visual Studio 2005 and you
       should be all set.

**This worked for me ... so hopefully this will work for you!**