# Security Exception with ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, securityexception

I get this, to me, completely random error:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +42
System.Web.UI.Util.GetTypeFromAssemblies(ICollection assemblies, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase) +145
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) +73
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) +111
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) +279
```

Whenever I try to run my asp.net site that uses a service I created.
The site is part of a project that also contains the service.

I don't use IIS or other stuff so don't tell me about that pool thing.

Edit:
I always have it

- New project with new service and web site;
- Framework 1.0 tot 4.0;
- Adding  to  in the web.config file;
- It's got nothing to do with IIS;

I might need to add that It's on my NAS.

Solved, well, partly, It gave the error because it was on my NAS.

Comment: Maybe run your VS as administrator?

Comment: Nope, already done that.

Comment: 3.5, the servers of my college are that. Other projects work.

Comment: Do you mean an actual Windows Service? How are you installing the service? What code is trying to use this service?

Comment: Exactly which version of Visual Studio are you using? There is no "Visual Studio 2011".

Comment: Duplicate of [Security Error in ASP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249134/security-error-in-asp-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is that it was located on my NAS and that caused security issues. Moving it to a folder in my PC solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is an interesting post. this guy had a similar issue when using AjaxControlToolkit.
Hope it helps:
[AjaxControlToolkit and SecurityException](http://www.phishthis.com/2009/03/11/ajaxcontroltoolkit-causes-systemsecuritysecurityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-systemwebaspnethostingpermission-failed/)

Comment: nope, that's not it. The problem is when I change my web.config file to framework 3.5.

I use Loginview btw.

Comment: desperately trying to help you man:

InsertAfter: /configuration/system.web/*[last()]
<trust level="Full" legacyCasModel="true" /

Comment: Nope not working. It's really strange and frustrating since it's the first time I get this.
The strange thing is that I can't find System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission in my web.config file. Adding it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Making a new clean 3.5 web site and copying that web.config file doesn't help either.

Comment: one more thing I can think of at the moment is that the trust level is set system wide in the machine.config or smth. and you are not allowed to override it

Comment: It's not only with framework 3.5, in 4.0 when I try to use MessageFault fault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
   XmlReader reader = fault.GetReaderAtDetailContents();
I get it as well

Comment: Solved, well, partly, It gave the error because it was on my NAS.