# System.Security.SecurityException when accessing local DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DLL that my organization uses placed inside the Bin/ folder of our web project. Right now, if I try to run the website locally through Visual Studio, I get this exception whenever I reference the assembly inside the DLL:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Why would I be getting a security exception when I'm trying to reference the DLL locally, from within the project? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973031/why-am-i-getting-this-error-system-security-securityexception-request-for-the?rq=1

Comment: @DavidTansey Maybe that? But I'm not running full IIS locally, just within Visual Studio.

Comment: I suggest you read this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249134/system-security-securityexception-thrown-by-asp-net-application?rq=1 it doesn't matter if your running through Visual Studio you still have to have the correct permissions.

Comment: I don't have a mscorcfg.msc on my system to configure the framework security settings. So no real idea where to look there.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the DLL, choosing the "properties" menu.  If there is an "unblock" option available, click it and try again.

Note that this would be caused by downloading the DLL from the internet, or extracting it from a zip file downloaded from the internet.

See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narahari/archive/2010/06/03/system-security-securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-web-aspnethostingpermission-system-version-2-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-b77a5c561934e089-failed.aspx).

Comment: I don't think it'd be this. The DLL is something that I've compiled myself, and included in the web project.

Comment: So you compiled the DLL on the computer you are testing on, as part of the project you are testing?  Are you referencing the project directly in VS?

Comment: Compiled DLL on the same computer, then copy paste it into the Bin/ folder.